# looping over legit parameters

Tags: python, parameters, iteration, lmfit

I am iterating over N files and fitting all the data using lmfit Gaussian Model. I would like to obtain an array of all the parameters for the different files so I can plot them against another variable. Any idea how to do so ?

this is my code:

```
def gaussian(x,center,sigma,amplitude):
    return amplitude*(1/(sigma*(np.sqrt(2*np.pi))))*np.exp(((-(x-center)**2))/(2*(sigma**2)))

for f in os.listdir(directory):    
    f= os.path.join(directory, f)  
    data=np.loadtxt(f)            

    x=data[np.where(data[:,0]<wavemax),0]
    y=data[np.where(data[:,0]<wavemax),1]
    x=x[0,np.where(x[0]>wavemin)][0]
    y=y[0,np.where(x>wavemin)][0]

    gauss1 = Model(gaussian,prefix='g1_')
    pars=gauss1.make_params()
    pars['g1_center'].set(2855.0, True, 2830.0, 2900.0)
    pars['g1_sigma'].set(6, True, 1.0, 20.0)
    pars['g1_amplitude'].set(0.6, True, 0.01, 30)

    gauss2 = Model(gaussian,prefix='g2_')
    pars.update(gauss2.make_params())
    pars['g2_center'].set(2900.0, True, 2850.0, 2950.0)
    pars['g2_sigma'].set(10.0, True, 1.0, 20.0)
    pars['g2_amplitude'].set(0.6, True, 0.01, 30)

    gauss3 = Model(gaussian,prefix='g3_')
    pars.update(gauss3.make_params())
    pars['g3_center'].set(2925.0, True, 2850.0, 2950.0)
    pars['g3_sigma'].set(10.0, True, 1.0, 50.0)
    pars['g3_amplitude'].set(3, True, 0.01, 30)

    gauss4 = Model(gaussian,prefix='g4_')
    pars.update(gauss4.make_params())
    pars['g4_center'].set(2970.0, True, 2850.0, 3000.0)
    pars['g4_sigma'].set(14.0, True, 1.0, 20.0)
    pars['g4_amplitude'].set(3, True, 0.01, 30)

    gauss5= Model(gaussian,prefix='g5_')
    pars.update(gauss5.make_params())
    pars['g5_center'].set(3050, True, 2750, 3050, None, None)
    pars['g5_sigma'].set(100, True, None, None, None, None)
    pars['g5_amplitude'].set(5, True, None, None, None, None)


    mod=gauss1+gauss2+gauss3+gauss4+gauss5 # fitting the entire curve 

    init = mod.eval(pars, x=x) #specifying the parameters for the fitting of all the curve
    out = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

make a `results` list before your loop, and for each fit, after the fit is complete, append `out.params` to that `results` list (and maybe other stuff to help mark fit details).

Then use the list of resulting fit parameters as you like.